# Parsing and searching a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to parse through a contacts list CSV file that looks like this:

```
First Name  Last Name  Full Name                            Short Name  Phone Number
Jenny       Smith      CN=Jenny Smith/OU=CORP/O=COMPANY     jesmi       6468675309
Mary        Poppin     CN=Mary Poppins/OU=STORE/O=COMPANY   mapop       7005555578
Tony        Stark      CN=Tony Stark/OU=STORE/O=COMPANY     tostar      6007777798
Peter       Parker     CN=Peter Parker/OU=NEWS/O=COMPANY    pepar       5008889090
```

I want to be able to search through column "Full Name" and select string "OU=STORE" and move all rows that contain "OU=STORE" aside, and then move it to it's own csv file called "store.csv". Then repeat the same process for "OU=CORP" and "OU=NEWS".

---

**This is what I want my output to look like:**

Store.csv should contain only this information once the process is done.

```
First Name  Last Name  Full Name                            Short Name  Phone Number
Mary        Poppin     CN=Mary Poppins/OU=STORE/O=COMPANY   mapop       7005555578
Tony        Stark      CN=Tony Stark/OU=STORE/O=COMPANY     tostar      6007777798
```

corp.csv

```
First Name  Last Name  Full Name                            Short Name  Phone Number
Jenny       Smith      CN=Jenny Smith/OU=CORP/O=COMPANY     jesmi       6468675309
```

news.csv

```
First Name  Last Name  Full Name                            Short Name  Phone Number    
Peter       Parker     CN=Peter Parker/OU=NEWS/O=COMPANY    pepar       5008889090
```

I have a small script of what I've done so far but I'm not sure what to do in the end:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

#this is the source folder    
source_dir = 'C:/Users/username/documents/contacts/contactslist.csv'

#this is the folder where I want to move the parsed data.
store_target_dir = 'C:/Users/username/documents/contacts/store/'
corp_target_dir = 'C:/Users/username/documents/contacts/corp/'
news_target_dir = 'C:/Users/username/documents/contacts/news/'

col_list = ["Full Name"]

store = 'OU=STORE'
corp = 'OU=CORP'
news = 'OU=NEWS'

#When it comes time to move the data to their folders with their csv name
csvName = store_target_dir + "/" + "store.csv"
csvName2 = corp_target_dir + "/" + "corp.csv"
csvName3 = news_target_dir + "/" +"news.csv"

#opening the file
file = open(source_dir)

#reading the csv file
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter you DataFrame, you could do something like this:

```
# key is the value you are looking for, e.g. 'OU=STORE'    
indices = [key in value for value in df['File Name']]
subset = df[indices]
```

`indices` is a bool list indicating whether a line contains `key` or not

Comment: Hi Tobiaaa, thank you again for this answer. I have one extra question, I didn't want to make a whole new post. But what if the key variable was a list with 4 or more strings inside we need to iterate through? I tried `key[i]`, but won't work.

Comment: So do you want to filter with multiple categories? Can you give me an example how a key list might look like?

If you want `subset` to contain all columns where "Full Name" contains at least one of the items in the key list, you could repeat the list comprehension from above for each item in the key list and append the `indices` list each time

Comment: Hi Tobiaaa, I actually ended up making a new post. It's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71399887/filter-a-dataframe-using-a-list

Comment: List would look like this `key = ['store', 'pharmacy', 'str1']`. The code before worked with just `key = 'store'`. I was thinking the code to look along the lines like this: `[[i for i in key] in row for row in df['Names']]` and `[[i for i in key] not in row for row in df['Names']]` in order to keep the same output as before.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the `OU=` value and add it as another column. `.unique()` could then be used to determine the 3 possible values and then each CSV created based on the that value. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('contactslist.csv', dtype={'Phone Number': str})
df['file'] = df['Full Name'].str.extract(r'OU=(\S+)/')

for key in df['file'].unique():
    df_filtered = df.loc[df['file'] == key]
    df_filtered = df_filtered.drop(['file'], axis=1)
    df_filtered.to_csv(f"{key}.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to not do too much modifications to your code a solution could look like this:

```py
import os, os.path
import csv

#this is the source folder
original_contacts_filename = r'C:\Users\username\documents\contacts\contactslist.csv'

#this is the folder where I want to move the parsed data.
store_target_dir = r'C:\Users\username\documents\contacts\store'
corp_target_dir = r'C:\Users\username\documents\contacts\corp'
news_target_dir = r'C:\Users\username\documents\contacts\news'

os.makedirs(store_target_dir, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(corp_target_dir, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(news_target_dir, exist_ok=True)

store = 'OU=STORE'
corp = 'OU=CORP'
news = 'OU=NEWS'

#When it comes time to move the data to their folders with their csv name
csv_name = os.path.join(store_target_dir, "store.csv")
csv_name2 = os.path.join(corp_target_dir, "corp.csv")
csv_name3 = os.path.join(news_target_dir, "news.csv")

with (
    open(original_contacts_filename, newline='') as original_contacts_file,
    open(csv_name, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file, 
    open(csv_name2, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file2, 
    open(csv_name3, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file3):

    original_contacts = csv.DictReader(original_contacts_file)
    
    store_destination = csv.writer(csv_file)
    corp_destination = csv.writer(csv_file2)
    news_destionation = csv.writer(csv_file3)

    output_headers = ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name', 'Short Name', 'Phone Number')
    store_destination.writerow(output_headers)
    corp_destination.writerow(output_headers)
    news_destionation.writerow(output_headers)

    for current_contact in original_contacts:
        if store in current_contact['Full Name']:
            output_destination = store_destination
        elif corp in current_contact['Full Name']:
            output_destination = corp_destination
        elif news in current_contact['Full Name']:
            output_destination = news_destionation
        else:
            output_destination = None
        
        if output_destination is not None:
            output_destination.writerow(current_contact[column] for column in output_headers)
```

But we can see a lot of repetitions which usually smells. We could simplyfy the code like this:

```py
import os, os.path
import csv
import re

original_contacts_filename = 'contactslist.csv'

source_directory = r'C:\Users\username\documents\contacts'

corporate_units_expected = ('store', 'corp', 'news')

target_directory = r'C:\Users\username\documents\contacts'
target_files_info = {
    current_unit: (
        current_name := os.path.join(target_directory, current_unit, f'{current_unit}2.csv'),
        open(current_name, 'w', newline='')
    )
    for current_unit in corporate_units_expected
}

for current_target, _ in target_files_info.values():
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(current_target), exist_ok=True)
    
matcher = re.compile(r'OU=([ 0-9a-zA-Z]+)')

with (
    open(original_contacts_filename, newline='') as original_contacts_file,
    target_files_info['store'][1], target_files_info['corp'][1], target_files_info['news'][1]
):
    original_contacts = csv.DictReader(original_contacts_file)

    writers = { 
        current_unit: csv.writer(current_target[1])
        for (current_unit, current_target) in target_files_info.items()
    }

    output_headers = ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name', 'Short Name', 'Phone Number')

    for current_writer in writers.values():
        current_writer.writerow(output_headers)
    
    for current_contact in original_contacts:
        if match_found := matcher.search(current_contact['Full Name']):
            current_writer = writers[match_found[1].lower()]
            current_writer.writerow(current_contact[column] for column in output_headers)
```

We could also have an example where we don't know in advance how many files we which to sort these entries into but it get a lot more complicated because we cannot use the `with` statement directly.