# Filter a Dataframe by iterating through a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe that I want to check if it contains certain data. If anything in the dataframe column `Names` has `store`, `pharmacy` or `str1`, then I want that row of data in a different file. And everything else in another.

I want to know if there is a way to search for these strings in the dataframe. I have this line of code with a for loop inside back when I had only one string `key='store'`, now it's a list as seen below:

```
key = ['store', 'pharmacy', 'str1'] #this is what I want to use now
#key = 'store' #this is what I had before

indiceName = [key in value for value in df['Names']]
subsetName = df[indiceName]
indiceStr  = [key not in row for row in df['Names']] 
subsetStr  = df[indiceStr]
```

Ouput looks like:

```
[False, False, True, True]
[True, True, False, False]
```

I want to keep it as that one line for loop. Is that possible?
Something like:

```
indiceName = [key[i] in value for value in df['Names']]
indiceStr  = [key[i] not in row for row in df['Names']]
```

Comment: See: [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: I reopened because I realized the duplicate doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.contains`:

```
df1 = df[df["Names"].str.lower().str.contains("|".join(key))]
df2 = df[~df["Names"].str.lower().str.contains("|".join(key))]
```

Comment: This is good! But I'm trying to maintain that one line for loop.

Comment: @NewTechie - You would need two loops. That is not as efficient as the above. But anyway, it would be `df[df["Names"].isin([n for n in df["Names"] if all(k not in n.lower() for k in key)])]`

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines like this: `[[i for i in key] in row for row in df['Names']]` and `[[i for i in key] not in row for row in df['Names']]` in order to keep the same output as before. This doesn't work, but it's the logic I'm going with.

Comment: What is wrong with the loop I suggested? What you have will not work as you want.

Comment: The only issue is that the output is not the same anymore, meaning I have make several changes throughout my script. But it's a list now and not just a single string. I might just need to do the necessary changes to get it to work with a list.

Comment: I figured it out, it works when I do this: `indiceStr = [any(x in row for x in key) for row in df['Names']]` and `indiceName = [all(not x in row for x in key) for row in df['Names']]`

Comment: Just note that you are using a double `for` loop for each list which is extremely inefficient compared to the vectorized `str.contains` method as in my answer.